# bundling of webpack takes insane amount of time

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gulp, gruntjs

Is this normal? it took 30-40s to bundle. Imagine I have to wait that amount of time when I make a small changes and click saved.

```
[16:53:44] Starting 'bundle'...
[16:54:29] [webpack]     Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
   app.js  3.87 MB       0  [emitted]  app
vendor.js  1.82 MB       1  [emitted]  vendor
[BS] Reloading Browsers...
[16:54:29] Finished 'bundle' after 45 s
```

Comment: Yes. It's normal. What time did you expect? Bundling isn't something you use for development. It's what you use once you're done. Bundling is also dependent on the specs of your development computer. The better the computer, the faster the bundling.

Comment: @Mjh the setup of the project is strange, I have to bundle to see my code changes.

Comment: Can't you split the project so that your changes are compiled to a separate file, while the rest is in another? If you need to rebuild everything every time to see your changes, you're doomed to waiting and then it's questionable why even use webpack *that way* if it annihilates your productivity..

Comment: @Mjh I'm new to the project, it's done that way by others. Now I'm thinking how to fix this.. what do you mean by separate file? in the bundle it has babel loader etc, webpack is needed.

Comment: In my experience, babel makes builds really slow, both with webpack and browserify. However, 40secs to bundle a standard js project with just thousands of lines of code is A LOT of time (maybe your project is really big?). You should probably add your webpack config and your `gulpfile`/ `gruntfile` to your question.